# How to make FrameLayout parent clickable if child views are taking whole parent width and height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have special layout using `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout`. Its form like layout but one `View` is only `TextInputEditText` by its look. It will not have any editable parts. Its purpose is to be informative and acts like `Button`. And there is a problem. I wrapped this `EditText` in `FrameLayout` and `FrameLayout` acts like `Button` which have `onClickListener`. Problem is that it is not reacting to clicks. How to enable it? ( `FrameLayout` should be in front of its children in terms of clickable area)

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/updateButton"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true">

       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/etLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           style="@style/form_edit_text_style"
           app:errorEnabled="true"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:hint="@string/et_hint_num">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                style="@style/form_inner_style"/>

       </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below custom FrameLayout:-

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // true if you do not want the children to be clickable.
        return mShouldInterceptAllTouch;
    }
}
```

Also, try:-

`focusableInTouchMode=false` for editText as editText is taking the focus.

Comment: This is working only If I click on this button once. As I return from previous Activity, view is not clickable anymore.

Comment: Did you return true from this method? also, did you set on-click listener to the frame layout?

Comment: Yes I made custom class where I return true as a constant.

Comment: Ok fixed. isEnabled was set to false as I switched from one activity to another.

Comment: Oh. Ok. No problem